# Is my use of "natural" correct?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, inversion, modifiers

My manager told my to answer customers' questions.

I want to say this answer for a specific question:

> We are providing services through smartphones applications. Each service has its own natural. For more information contact me please.

I am not asking if the content of the message is correct. But I am asking if this sentence is grammatical because I want to show it to customers.

Comment: Please be specific about what you think might be wrong with the sentence.

Comment: @MattEllen using natural word

Comment: you mean the sentence "Each service has its own natural"?

Comment: @MattEllen yes exactly

Comment: How 'content' is correct but grammar is wrong!

Comment: @MaulikV i dont know , i am not good at english

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Ah, no offense! I just wondered what you meant. I'm also sailing in the same boat, buddy!

Comment: @MaulikV `How 'content' is correct but grammar is wrong!` I would say in the first sentence that is the case. `*smartphones applications` should be `smartphone applications`, but arguably, the content of the sentence is correct.

Comment: @oerkelens so u mean that using `natural` is correct please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say "smartphone applications" (not smartphones).

But what I wonder about a lot more is the use of "natural". It can be used as a noun, meaning someone who has a natural talent for doing something.

I do not understand what the word would mean in the area of smartphone applications.

Then again, it is possible that your customer will fully understand this word in its context, in which case the message looks fine to me (it consists of three sentences by the way).

I understand that intend "natural" to mean "functionality", I am guessing this stems from "natural" being a translation of "characteristic" or "property" or some such word from your mother tongue.

The noun "natural" in English has a very different meaning, however. It is a person with a remarkable natural talent:

> He is a natural at chess!

To describe functionality of your applications, you can use **functionality**, **purpose**, **property**, **characteristic**. There are more words that could fit your purpose.

Comment: i dont know if using "natural" is good. the customers are asking. what is your company do. so i used natural. if you konw a better word, tell please

Comment: I don;t know what natural means to you. Can you explain what you mean with it?

Comment: i mean each service has difference functionality

Comment: Then I would suggest you use that. "Each service has its own specific functionality".